# How to automatically update an application without ClickOnce?

Tags: c#, deployment

For the project I am working on, I am not allowed to use [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce). My boss wants the program to look "real" (with an installer, etc).

I have installed [Visual Studio 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012) Professional, and have been playing around with the [InstallShield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InstallShield) installer, and it definitely makes nice installers, but I can't figure out how to enable the application to "auto-update" (that is, when it starts up, checks to make sure that it is using the latest version).

I have been asked to make a tiny change to the code - switching an addition to a subtraction, and I don't really want people to have to uninstall the old version, and then have to reinstall the new version every time I make a small change like this.

How can I make the application check for updates, and install them? Or is this not possible (or not easy)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-update library for .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691663/auto-update-library-for-net)

Comment: You could use [Google Omaha](https://github.com/google/omaha). It's what Chrome uses and gives you a nice installer _and_ auto-updates.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are a lot of questions already about this, so I will refer you to those.

One thing you want to make sure to prevent the need for uninstallation, is that you use the same **upgrade** code on every release, but change the **product** code. These values are located in the Installshield project properties.

Some references:

- [Auto update .NET applications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/819647/161052)
- [Auto-update library for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/691663/161052)
- [Auto update for WinForms application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/139266/161052)
- [Suggest a method for auto-updating my C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/555118/161052)
- [Automatic update a Windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4769615/161052)

Comment: I have tried this - going in and changing the product code. But when I go to reinstall, It says that it is installing, but doesn't change the program at all.... any ideas? thanks :)

Comment: Oh, it appears it did actually re-install it (several times), but never updated the files on my computer

Comment: Was the already-installed version done so using the same Upgrade Code as your current installer? If not, you may need to use Orca. Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11540520/161052

Comment: it was the same, yes. Apparently it is something about upgrade paths - but since I am using the limited version, I am not sure if I can resolve this

Comment: Not seeming to work, following your exact steps, and it is still just installing a second application. Ugh most frustrating thing ever

Comment: Try using Orca to see if the upgrade code in the installed app (the one you want to replace) matches the code you're using now.

Comment: thanks for all the help! I will try orca (once the SDK finishes installing)

Comment: Ok, I got Orca working, and I have verified that the productCode is different, and the Upgrade code is the same. Still it is just installing a second copy of the application. My exact steps are as follows: Change my application code : build my application : Get a new ProductCode : Build the installer (setup) : locate setup.msi, to install. But like I said - it still just creates a second copy. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You might try to resequence "RemoveExistingProducts" - this can be found on the InstallShield "Upgrade Paths" section. IS offers some useful information regarding the global assembly cache and a Windows Installer problem that it's intended to work around. It also references Microsoft Knowledge Base 905238.

Comment: The answers in all linked references largely refer to using ClickOnce, which the OP has stated as a clear limitation. I don't see how this is a good answer.

Answer (score 7):

I think you should check the following project at codeplex.com
http://autoupdater.codeplex.com/

This sample application is developed in C# as a library with the project name “AutoUpdater”. The DLL “AutoUpdater” can be used in a C# Windows application(WinForm and WPF).

There are certain features about the AutoUpdater:

1. Easy to implement and use.
2. Application automatic re-run after checking update.
3. Update process transparent to the user.
4. To avoid blocking the main thread using multi-threaded download.
5. Ability to upgrade the system and also the auto update program.
6. A code that doesn't need change when used by different systems and
   could be compiled in a library.
7. Easy for user to download the update files.

How to use?

In the program that you want to be auto updateable, you just need to call the AutoUpdate function in the Main procedure. The AutoUpdate  function will check the version with the one read from a file located in a Web Site/FTP. If the program version is lower than the one read the program downloads the auto update program and launches it and the function returns True, which means that an auto update will run and the current program should be closed. The auto update program receives several parameters from the program to be updated and performs the auto update necessary and after that launches the updated system.

```
  #region check and download new version program
  bool bSuccess = false;
  IAutoUpdater autoUpdater = new AutoUpdater();
  try
  {
      autoUpdater.Update();
      bSuccess = true;
  }
  catch (WebException exp)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Can not find the specified resource");
  }
  catch (XmlException exp)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Download the upgrade file error");
  }
  catch (NotSupportedException exp)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Upgrade address configuration error");
  }
  catch (ArgumentException exp)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Download the upgrade file error");
  }
  catch (Exception exp)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("An error occurred during the upgrade process");
  }
  finally
  {
      if (bSuccess == false)
      {
          try
          {
              autoUpdater.RollBack();
          }
          catch (Exception)
          {
             //Log the message to your file or database
          }
      }
  }
  #endregion
```

Answer (score 4):

The most common way would be to put a simple text file (XML/JSON would be better) on your webserver with the last build version. The application will then download this file, check the version and start the updater. A typical file would look like this:

Application Update File (**A unique string that will let your application recognize the file type**)

version: 1.0.0 (**Latest Assembly Version**)

download: http://yourserver.com/... (**A link to the download version**)

redirect: http://yournewserver.com/... (**I used this field in case of a change in the server address.**)

**This would let the client know that they need to be looking at a new address.**

You can also add other important details.

Comment: that makes sense. but how do you avoid the message of: "Another version of this project is already installed ...." when you go to re-install?

Comment: as pointed by @JYelton keep the same update code. There are other ways, but I forgot :(

Answer (score 2):

A Lay men's way is

on Main() rename the executing assembly file .exe to some thing else
check date and time of created.
and the updated file date time and copy to the application folder.

```
//Rename he executing file
System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

System.IO.File.Move(file.FullName, file.DirectoryName + "\\" + file.Name.Replace(file.Extension,"") + "-1" + file.Extension);
```

then do the logic check and copy the new file to executing folder

Answer (score 1):

This is the code to update the file but not to install
This program is made through dos for copying files to the latest date and run your program automatically. may help you

open notepad and save file below with ext .bat

```
xcopy \\IP address\folder_share_name\*.* /s /y /d /q  
start "label" /b "youraplicationname.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

These days you could use included in Windows 10 mechanism for app delivery called AppInstaller by packaging your app in MSIX bundle or package.

With it, you don't have to think about an installer (if your app doesn't use a lot of dependencies), background updating, and all of that. It's much better than ClickOnce, command-line usage works like a charm thanks to aliases, updates are non-obtrusive and could be used for background apps too.

The installation experience is much better too: a user just needs to click a button on HTML and Windows will install the app automatically.

It's not super-simple, I'd say more complicated than ClickOnce, but not as hard as Wix.

[Official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) doesn't work with .NET Core or .NET 5 apps, so you can refer to [this article](https://www.meziantou.net/deploying-a-dotnet-desktop-application-using-msix.htm#creating-the-msix-pa-3a8341), or to [this great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4t2TI8ImwMY), for example. [This site](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-introduction.html) also contains a lot of useful information.