# C# Auto Updater

Tags: c#, git, monogame, automatic-updates

I'm currently developing a Platformer using Monogame in order to learn C# again because I haven't used it for 2 years. I'm using Microsoft VSTS to remotely have it in a Git repository.

My brothers are going to be my beta testers and before I give them the game I'd like to implement automatic updates.
I'd like to create an installer that they use to install the game but after that the game automatically checks for updates at launch.

Is it possible to do that using Git as version control and only download changes every time it launches instead of a complete reinstall?

How would I go about doing something like that? I've googled a lot but haven't found a good answer yet. This is something I wanted to do years ago when using C# as well but never found a solution.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: UWP has support for this. MSIX will add support for this soon. ClickOnce allows complete updates, but only downloads changed assemblies.

Comment: GIT is not designed for binary diffs, it can be made to work, but not advised. You should be using ClickOnce. See [How to automatically update an application without ClickOnce?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12787761/402022) for a few alternatives. See [Game launcher / updater download delta diff](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/138654/10408) if you want cook your own.

Comment: Take a look at Squirrel: It's like ClickOnce but Works™

Comment: Thanks guys! I'll take a look at those links as well as Squirrel

Answer (score 1):

Try clickonce.. it may help you.if you are trying to do automatic update on client installation whenever new version is deplayed in application server or network share